Background-image in CSS url blocked by Opaque Response Blocking
In Django I use a background-image stored on a remote web-storage (Digitalocean Spaces) like this:
<style>
    .bg-image {
        background-image: url("{{ instance.background.url }}");
    }
</style>

but the request gets blocked A resource is blocked by OpaqueResponseBlocking.
The same image is loaded in another place on the same page through a img tag without problems.
To understand the problem: What is the difference on the server-side requests that the css-url gets blocked while the img-url passes?


From where you are loading image from. Is it present in your django project?

@RohitRajput On a remote web-storage (S4), I updated the question.

Ok so issue may be not in your django webapp, the server from where you are loading image from may not have header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. to check if has, you can go to the image url and open inspect and go to network and refresh the page to capture the request, find the packet requesting image, and look it's response, it may not have: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Background images are loaded with Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors, therefore the CORS settings have no effect. Does the server of the image set a Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header?

@HeikoTheißen Do you mean in the response headers? No. But if of interest: vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method

See https://github.com/annevk/orb. What's the Content-Type response header of your image?

@HeikoTheißen content-type: application/xml

That seems wrong for an image, and https://github.com/annevk/orb calls that an "opaque-blocklisted MIME type".

What browser are you using? Mine (Chrome 128) does not implement ORB++.

@HeikoTheißen Chrome 128 and Firefox 130. Thanks for pointing out the underlying problem. I hoped adding Content-Type: application/xml would solve my issue, but no.

The specific problem here is that I used the <style> tag to set up the background-image. This - i guess - forced django to send the request with Content-Type: application/xml that gets blocked.
Changing the code to:
<div style="background-image: url('{{ instance.background.url }}');">
    ...
</div>

fixed the problem.

So it was not the image request that was blocked, but rather the stylesheet request?

@HeikoTheißen I am not dev enough to answer this question. Had a class definition inside a <style> tag embedded in normal html. Getting rid of the <style> tag solved everything.

Opaque response blocking is a new feature waiting to be incorporated into the fetch standard, see https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/1755. Its aim is stated as follows:

Essentially, CSS, JavaScript, images, and media (audio and video) can be requested across
origins without the CORS protocol. And unfortunately except for CSS there is no MIME type
enforcement. This algorithm aims to block as many responses as possible that are not one of these
types (or are newer variants of those types) to avoid leaking their contents through side channels.

Browsers implementing this feature would block images and stylesheets that are served with an XML mime type (for example, Content-Type: application/xml), but Content-Type: image/svg+xml is allowed.

Thanks for sending me on the right track to a solution.
